# Retornar objeto numa ArrayList pelo ID

Tags: java, arraylist

Boa tarde galera, tudo bem?

Preciso de uma ajuda rapida, estou com dificuldade em fazer esse codigo abaixo rodar corretamente, eu tenho uma arraylist onde eu cadastrei dois itens, um com ID=1 e outro com ID=2, mas na parte de procurar pelo ID digitado no terminal ele só procura no primeiro item da array e dpois sai do FOR.

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import modelo.Produto;
import utils.Utils;

public class Mercado {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static ArrayList<Produto> produtos;
    private static Map<Produto, Integer> carrinho;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        produtos = new ArrayList<>();
        carrinho = new HashMap<>();
        menu();
    }

private static void comprarProdutos() {
        if(produtos.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Lista de produtos! \n");
            
            System.out.println("----------Produtos Disponiveis---------");
            for (Produto p : produtos) {
                System.out.println(p + "\n");
            }
            int id = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            boolean isPresent = false;
            
            for (Produto p : produtos) {
                if(p.getId() == id) {
                    int qtd = 0;
                    try {
                        qtd = carrinho.get(p);
                        // checa se o produto já esta no carrinho, incrementa quantidade
                        carrinho.put(p, qtd + 1);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // se o produto for o primeiro no carrinho
                        carrinho.put(p, 1);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println(p.getNome() + " adicionado ao carrinho.");
                    isPresent = true;
                    
                    if (isPresent) {
                        System.out.println("Deseja adicionar outro produto ao carrinho?");
                        System.out.println("Digite 1 para sim, ou 0 para finalizar a compra. \n");
                        int option = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                        
                        if (option == 1) {
                            comprarProdutos();
                        } else {
                            menu();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Produto não encontrado");
                    menu();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

Prezado fiz alterações no seu código para deixá-lo funcionando, veja que inicialmente populei o array de produtos:

```
public class Mercado {

private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Produto> produtos;
private static Map<Produto, Integer> carrinho;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Produto p1 = new Produto();
    p1.setId(1);
    p1.setNome("leite");
    Produto p2 = new Produto();
    p2.setId(2);
    p2.setNome("ovos");
    produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    produtos.add(p1);
    produtos.add(p2);
    carrinho = new HashMap<>();
    comprarProdutos();
}

private static void comprarProdutos() {
    if(produtos.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Lista de produtos! \n");
        
        System.out.println("----------Produtos Disponiveis---------");
        for (Produto p : produtos) {
            System.out.println(p.getNome() + "\n");
        }
        int id = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        boolean isPresent = false;
        
        for (Produto p : produtos) {
            if(p.getId() == id) {
                int qtd = 0;
                try {
                    qtd = carrinho.get(p);
                    // checa se o produto já esta no carrinho, incrementa quantidade
                    carrinho.put(p, qtd + 1);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    // se o produto for o primeiro no carrinho
                    carrinho.put(p, 1);
                }
                
                System.out.println(p.getNome() + " adicionado ao carrinho.");
                isPresent = true;
                
                if (isPresent) {
                    System.out.println("Deseja adicionar outro produto ao carrinho?");
                    System.out.println("Digite 1 para sim, ou 0 para finalizar a compra. \n");
                    int option = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                    
                    if (option == 1) {
                        comprarProdutos();
                    } else {
                        //Imprime a lista total:
                        System.out.println("Lista final de compras: ");
                        for (Map.Entry<Produto, Integer> carro : carrinho.entrySet()) {
                            System.out.println(carro.getKey().getNome() + ":" + carro.getValue());
                        }
                      //  menu();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Produto não encontrado");
              //  menu();
            }
        }
    }}
    }
```

Classe Produto:

```
public class Produto {

private Integer id;

private String nome;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}}
```